# django model object filter

Tags: python, database, django, django-forms

I have tables called 'has_location' and 'locations'. 'has_location' has `user_has` and `location_id` and its own `id` which is given by django itself.

'locations' have more columns.

Now I want to get all locations of some certain user. What I did is..(user.id is known):

```
users_locations_id = has_location.objects.filter(user_has__exact=user.id)
locations = Location.objects.filter(id__in=users_locations_id)
print len(locations)
```

but I am getting `0` by this `print`. I have data in db. but I have the feeling that `__in` does not accept the models id, does it ?

thanks

Comment: Can you show us the relevant parts of these three model definitions, please?

Comment: @GarethRees, sure but they are just a normal models. i think, the point here is more about what i can use ``__in`` on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using has_location's own id to filter locations. You have to use `location_id`s to filter locations:

```
user_haslocations = has_location.objects.filter(user_has=user)
locations = Location.objects.filter(id__in=user_haslocations.values('location_id'))
```

You can also filter the locations directly through the reverse relation:

```
location = Location.objects.filter(has_location__user_has=user.id)
```

Answer (score 11):

Using `__in` for this kind of query is a common anti-pattern in Django: it's tempting because of its simplicity, but it scales poorly in most databases. See slides 66ff in [this presentation by Christophe Pettus](http://www.slideshare.net/OReillyOSCON/unbreaking-your-django-application).

You have a many-to-many relationship between users and locations, represented by the `has_location` table. You would normally describe this to Django using a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) with a `through` table, something like this:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    # ...

class User(models.Model):
    locations = models.ManyToManyField(Location, through = 'LocationUser')
    # ...

class LocationUser(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    class Meta:
         db_table = 'has_location'
```

Then you can fetch the locations for a user like this:

```
user.locations.all()
```

You can query the locations in your filter operations:

```
User.objects.filter(locations__name = 'Barcelona')
```

And you can request that users' related locations be fetched efficiently using the [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) method on a query set.

Comment: wow, very nice. i have a poor database knowledge, very helpful guidance, thanks in tons.

Comment: It's definitely worth learning about databases if you are writing Django applications. (Otherwise one day you'll find that your application is running way too slowly and you have no idea how to fix it.) A good first step is to turn on query logging in your database and monitor the log as you test your Django site to see what queries are actually being executed.

Answer (score 1):

What do your models look like?

For your doubt, `__in` [does accept](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/querysets/#in) filtered ids.

For your current code, the solution:

```
locations = Location.objects.filter(id__in=has_location.objects.filter(user=user).values('location_id'))
# if you just want the length of the locations, evaluate locations.count()
locations.count()
# if you want to iterate locations to access items afterwards
len(locations)
```